# Регулярное выражение только для Int и только для одного символа

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно извлечь из строки, с помощью регулярных выражений, все числа (т.е 1 2 3, но не 1.1 или 14.14 - это уже дабл) и все одиночные буквенные символы (т.е а б в a b c).

Как это лучше сделать, "\d+" выводит и дабл, просто пропуская точку, т.е 14.14 оно распознает как 14 и 14. То же самое и с символами "\w{1,1}", выводит все символы, деля строки на отдельные символы.

Comment: с буквами проще, их можно обернуть в `\b`

Comment: Попробуйте `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?U)(?<![0-9]\\.{0,1})[0-9]+(?!\\.?[0-9])|\b\\p{L}\\b");`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать

```
(?U)(?<![0-9]\.{0,1})[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])|\b\p{L}\b
```

Java:

```
String regex = "(?U)(?<![0-9]\\.{0,1})[0-9]+(?!\\.?[0-9])|\\b\\p{L}\\b";
```

См. [демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B0-9%5D%5C.%7B0%2C1%7D%29%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F!%5C.%3F%5B0-9%5D%29%7C%5Cb%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cb&i=1%202%203%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%201.1%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%2014.14%20%26%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%20%D0%B2%20a%20b%20c) (так эта регулярка будет работать в Java)

- `(?U)` - `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`, граница слова начнёт распознавать границы слов в Юникоде
- `(?<![0-9]\\.{0,1})` - перед следующей цифрой не должно быть цифры или цифры и точки
- `[0-9]+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?!\\.?[0-9])` - сразу после цифры, найденной с помощью `[0-9]+`, не должно быть другой цифры или точки и цифры
- `|` - или
- `\\b` - граница слова
- `\\p{L}` - буква
- `\\b` - граница слова

По-другому, без опционального знака `.` в блоке предварительного просмотра назад, этот шаблон можно написать так:

```
(?<![0-9]\.)(?<![0-9])[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])|\b\p{L}\b
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/iJQqT6/2). Или вот так:

```
(?<![0-9]\.|[0-9])[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])|\b\p{L}\b
```

[Ещё одно демо](https://regex101.com/r/iJQqT6/3).